# Fallback from dynamic error page to static error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, web-config, custom-error-pages

I know, we should always use static error pages, but in my case I've got to use a dynamic error page "ErrorPage.aspx" with a .cs file. Now since we are running a security audit for https certificate; it shows a very possible scenario where there might be an error in this ErrorPage.aspx itself.

I've specified the custom error element in the web config which redirects any error to this dynamic page and as usual have set the mode to on.

e.g.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" >
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="Login.aspx"/>
     </customErrors>
```

Now what if there's an error in error page, where shall I redirect it. Therefore, in my first attempt, I added a static html page error.htm to the project and in my errorpage.aspx's page directive I added errorpage="error.htm". But it's not working, instead it shows me a web config error saying I should set mode to "RemoteOnly".

I think I need to check explicitly the error codes in errorpage.aspx and then perform the re-direction but that'll be quite lengthy. I want to know if there's a better option to do it.

I hope I've made my problem clear.

Comment: And then what if somehow there were errors in your production web config, cause you not to be able to redirect anywhere in your application.